# Structure decclaration in c

Tags: c, compilation, nested, structure

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct parent{
int a;
int b;
struct child{
char*c ;
} c = {"child"};
} p = {1,2};
void main()
{}
```

**Why does the above code cause compilation error?**

Comment: Because it is invalid C code and the error is the method the compiler uses to tell you that?

Comment: You should post a question if the above code compiles, it'll be a sign for the end of the world.

Comment: What did you want to obtain with your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

write like as following code

```
struct parent{
    int a;
    int b;
    struct child{
        char*c ;
    } c;
} p = {1,2, {"child"}};
```